# Obtaining value obtained by javascript using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was able to extract user information from the social Graph API and display it on my site within  tags . How do I now get this information, and use it in a PHP script? In other words, say I want to use PHP to calculate the weather, but only based on the preferred weather on a users facebook profile(hypothetical situation). Now, assuming I have obtained the users preferred weather using javascript, how do I use PHP to get that information in order to perform my calculations? I guess one way would be to use regular expressions to match the values on the same page, but that seems tedious. Any help/direction is appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If the question is how can php get the data to process it, then you could use ajax to send it to php from the javascript.  If the question is how do you process the data in php, then it really depends on the format of the data you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using php to access the Facebook API or the pre built HTML they provide?  You should use php to retrieve the data, do what you need to do with the data, and then display it on a webpage, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get the data, then send it to your php script using AJAX, but this is a round-about way of doing it.

You can make the call the to the Graph API directly from your PHP script.  Something like this:

```
$r = new HttpRequest('https://socialgraph.googleapis.com/<method_name>', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
```

You will need to parse the data when you get the response -- `json_decode()` should do the trick.